# Pre selected Rows with Pagination not working in Datatable in Saleforce LWC

Tags: javascript, datatable, salesforce, apex, lwc

I am loading the user table data to datatable using LWC, the users who has not logging past two months. When the page loads first time I load all the list to front end and using pagination Im going through the records instead going to the server again. Based on the list we can deactivate the users or exclude the user using a checkbox.

Initially all checkbox should come as true but only first page will checked as true. The other pages checkboxes are not checked. Pre selected Row Ids are send to the UI via controller to checked or unchecked. Another issue I faced is the selected checkboxes are not selected when move to another page and coming back to the same page. The selected Ids will be send to the system by clicking the **Deactivate Users** button.

[image: Page 1 Pre selected Rows checkbox as true]

[image: Page 2 or others Pre selected Rows checkbox are not checked]

**Wrapper Class**

public class UserMngtWrapper {

```
//User Id
public String UserId {get; set;}
//User FullName
public String FullName {get; set;}
//User Email
public String Email {get; set;}
//User ProfileName
public String ProfileName {get; set;}
//User RoleName
public String RoleName {get; set;}
//User is Frozen
public String isFrozen {get; set;}
//User Last Login Date
public Datetime LastLoginDate {get; set;}
//User Last Modified Date by user
public String LastModifiedDate {get; set;}
//User Created Date
public String CreatedDate {get; set;}
//User is Active
public String isActive {get; set;}
//User is Deactivated
public String isDeactivate {get; set;}
```

}

**Controller**

public  class UserManagementController {

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static string getUserList() {
    List<UserMngtWrapper> userMngtWrapperList = new List<UserMngtWrapper>();
    UserListMngtWrapper userListMngtWrapper = new UserListMngtWrapper();
    Set<Id> selectedIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    //Get last two months inactive users
    Set<ID> inactiveUserIds = new Map<Id,User>([SELECT id From User
                                                WHERE LastLoginDate < LAST_N_DAYS: 60
                                                      AND IsActive = TRUE                                                                                                                
                                                      AND CreatedDate < LAST_N_DAYS: 60
                                                ]).keySet();
    //Get last two months inactive users Data
    List<User> userList = [Select  id,Profile.Name,Name,Email,UserRole.Name,LastLoginDate,LastModifiedDate,CreatedDate,IsActive,IsDeactivate__c   FROM User where id= : inactiveUserIds order by Profile.Name asc,Name asc];
    
    for (User u : userList)
    {
        UserMngtWrapper userMngtWrapper = new UserMngtWrapper();
        userMngtWrapper.UserId = u.id;
        userMngtWrapper.FullName = (u.Name != null ) ? u.Name: '';
        userMngtWrapper.Email = (u.Email != null ) ? u.Email: '';
        userMngtWrapper.LastLoginDate =  u.LastLoginDate;
        userMngtWrapper.ProfileName =  (u.Profile.Name != null ) ? u.Profile.Name: '';
        userMngtWrapper.RoleName =  (u.UserRole.Name != null ) ? u.UserRole.Name: '';
        userMngtWrapper.isDeactivate =  (u.IsDeactivate__c == false  ) ? 'FALSE': 'TRUE' ;
        userMngtWrapperList.add(userMngtWrapper);
        selectedIdSet.add(u.Id);
    }

    userListMngtWrapper.userMngtWrapperList = userMngtWrapperList;
    userListMngtWrapper.selectedUserIdSet = selectedIdSet;
    return JSON.serialize(userListMngtWrapper);
}


@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Boolean userRecordsUpdate() {
   // inprogress
    Return true;
}

**Wrapper List Class**
public class UserListMngtWrapper{
    @AuraEnabled public List<UserMngtWrapper> userMngtWrapperList {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public set<Id> selectedUserIdSet {get; set;}
}
```

}

**JS**

```js
import { LightningElement , track, wire,api } from 'lwc';
import getUserList from '@salesforce/apex/UserManagementController.getUserList';
import userRecordsUpdate from '@salesforce/apex/UserManagementController.userRecordsUpdate';
import {refreshApex} from '@salesforce/apex';

export default class Usermanagement extends LightningElement {
 @track  columns = [
    { label: 'User Id',fieldName: 'UserId',type: 'text',sortable: false,cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' },initialWidth: 200,},
    { label: 'Name',fieldName: 'FullName',type: 'text',sortable: false,cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' },initialWidth: 200,},
    { label: 'Email',fieldName: 'Email',type: 'text',sortable: false,cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' },initialWidth: 200,},
    { label: 'Profile Name',fieldName: 'ProfileName',type: 'text',sortable: false,cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' },initialWidth: 200,},
    { label: 'Role Name',fieldName: 'RoleName',type: 'text',sortable: false,cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' },initialWidth: 200,},
    {
            label: "Last Login Date",
            fieldName: "LastLoginDate",
            type: "date",
            typeAttributes:{
                year: "numeric",
                month: "2-digit",
                day: "2-digit",
                hour: "2-digit",
                minute: "2-digit",
                second: "2-digit"
            },
            sortable: false,cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' },
            initialWidth: 200,
        },
        { label: 'Deactivate',fieldName: 'isDeactivate',type: 'text',sortable: false,cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' },initialWidth: 200,}

];

     @track showLoadingSpinner = false;
     @track error;
     @track page = 1;
     @track perpage = 5;
     @track pages = [];
     @track disabledConditionNext =false;
     @track disabledConditionPrev =false;
     @track disabledCondition = true;
     @track preSelectedRows=[];
     @track totalRecordCount=0;
     data=[];
     @track numberOfPages =1;
     numOfPreviousPages;
     set_size = 5;
     
     connectedCallback() {
        this.init();
     }
    
     async init()
     {
                 try {
                this.disabledCondition = true;
                this.showLoadingSpinner = true;
                await getUserList()
                 .then((result,error) => {
                     var userList = JSON.parse(result);

                     if (userList) {
this.data=userList.userMngtWrapperList;
                         this.preSelectedRows = userList.selectedUserIdSet;
                         this.data = this.data;
                        this.totalRecordCount = this.data.length;
                     } else if (error) {
                         console.error(error);
                     }
                 });
                    this.disabledConditionPrev =false;
                    this.disabledConditionNext =false;
                    this.disabledCondition = false;
                    this.setPages(this.data);
                    this.showLoadingSpinner = false;

             } catch (error) {
                      this.error = error;
                  } finally {
                      this.showLoadingSpinner = false;
                  }
         }
         
         get currentPageData(){
                       return this.pageData();
                    }
         
         get pagesList(){
        let mid = Math.floor(this.set_size/2) + 1 ;
        if(this.page > mid){
            return this.pages.slice(this.page-mid, this.page+mid-1);
        }
            return this.pages.slice(0,this.set_size);
     }
     
        pageData = ()=>{
                             let numberOfPages = Math.ceil(this.data.length / this.perpage);
                             this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
                             let page = this.page;
                             let perpage = this.perpage;
                             let startIndex = (page*perpage) - perpage;
                             let endIndex = (page*perpage);
                             if(this.numberOfPages < 1)
                             {
                                this.disabledConditionPrev =true;
                                this.disabledConditionNext =true;
                             }
                             return this.data.slice(startIndex,endIndex);
                          }

        setPages = (data)=>{
                                      let numberOfPages = Math.ceil(data.length / this.perpage);
                                      this.numOfPreviousPages = numberOfPages;

                                  }


        onNext = ()=>{
                                      if(this.page < this.numberOfPages){
                                         ++this.page;
                                          this.disabledConditionNext =false;
                                          this.disabledConditionPrev =false;
                                          this.hasPageChanged =true;
                                         
                                      }
                                      else {
                                          this.disabledConditionNext =true;                            this.disabledConditionPrev =false;

                                      }

                                  }

        onPrev = ()=>{
                                      if(this.page > 1){
                                            --this.page;
                                            this.disabledConditionPrev =false;
                                            this.disabledConditionNext =false;
                                      }
                                      else {
                                            this.disabledConditionPrev =true;
                                            this.disabledConditionNext =false;
                                      }
                                  }

      onFirst = ()=>{
              this.page = 1;
              }

      onLast = ()=>{
              this.page = this.numberOfPages;
              }

              onPageClick = (e)=>{
                        this.page = parseInt(e.target.dataset.id,10);
                        if(this.numberOfPages < 1)
                        {
                            this.disabledConditionPrev =true;
                            this.disabledConditionNext =true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             this.disabledConditionPrev =false;
                             this.disabledConditionNext =false;
                        }
                    }

       // Method didnt develop and test
    updateRecords(){
             var selectedRecords =
              this.template.querySelector("lightning-datatable").getSelectedRows();
              let arrset = [];
              selectedRecords.forEach(row => {
                                 arrset.push(row.userId);
                             });
              userRecordsUpdate()
             .then(result=>{
               return refreshApex(this.refreshTable);
             })
             .catch(error=>{
               alert('Could not update(error));
             })
           }


**HTML**
```

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card   title="User Management" icon-name="standard:user" class="slds-col slds-size_12-of-12 slds-p-top_small">
        <lightning-button slot="actions" label="Deactivate Users" onclick={updateRecords}></lightning-button>
        <div class="slds-p-left_medium">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_12-of-12 slds-p-top_medium">
                <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg">

                    <lightning-datatable
                            key-field="UserId"
                            columns={columns}
                            data={currentPageData}
                            selected-rows= {preSelectedRows}
                            onrowaction={getRowActions}
                            >
                    </lightning-datatable>
                </div>

                <div class="slds-col slds-size_10-of-12 slds-p-top_medium">
                    <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true">
                        <lightning-layout-item size = "12" margin= "around-small">
                            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                                <ul class="slds-button-group-row">
                                    <li class="slds-button-group-item" >
                                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" disabled={disabledCondition} onclick ={onFirst}> First
                                        </button>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="slds-button-group-item" >
                                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" disabled={disabledConditionPrev} onclick ={onPrev}> Prev
                                        </button>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="slds-button-group-item" >
                                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral"  disabled={disabledConditionNext} onclick={onNext} >Next</button>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="slds-button-group-item" >
                                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral"  disabled={disabledCondition} onclick ={onLast}> Last
                                        </button>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            </br>
                            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" >
                                <span>Total Records: {totalRecordCount} </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" >
                                <span>Page ({page} of {numberOfPages}) </span>
                            </div>


                        </lightning-layout-item>
                    </lightning-layout>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div if:true={showLoadingSpinner}>
            <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="large"></lightning-spinner>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Summarize the Issues are,

1. Pre selected Row Ids are only selected or checked in page 1. Not checked in other pages.(`selected-rows= {preSelectedRows}`)
2. The selected checkboxes are not selected(checked box unchecked) after move to another page and coming back to the same page. Selected items should remain even going though any paginations and come back to the same page.

Could you please help me on this.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Lightning data-table easily helps us to show large data in tabular format, with a flexible selection approach.

When pagination applies with the LWC: Datatable pre-selected-rows, it does not work straightforward way. Because apply pagination helps to display only selected page information and hide the rest of the records actually they are not populated yet.

So when you want to know about the selected rows from the data table, it gives you results in only the current page information not persist the previous or next page configured selected records.

To resolve the selection issue, we need to store the selected records page-wise.

When the user selects any page, the storage helps to populate his previous selected options. If he has done any new selection update. The system will also update the storage with the newly selected option.

This process is implemented in the below article

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/lwc-datatable-way-programmatically-handle-preselect-siddiquee/